# Size of Formulas with no negative sign for Matrix Permanent

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, permanent, formulas

What is the best lower bound for algebraic formulas for Permanent of a matrix given that the formulas have no negative sign? Is there an exponential lower bound known for such formulas and what would be a good reference on the topic?

Comment: You might also be interested to know that Valiant proved there are polynomials where there is an exponential gap between their monotone and non-monotone algebraic circuit complexities (in particular, the perfect matching polynomial for a certain family of graphs). See: http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800135.804412

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Snir](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-10003-2_103) has proved a tight lower bound on the size of monotone formulas representing the permanent of an $n\times n$ matrix. The lower bound is $2^{2n - 0.25\log^2 n}$, and he notes that a formula of size $2^{2n - 0.25\log^2 n + O(\log n)}$ exists (Theorem 3.1. and comment after the proof).

The [survey](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shpilka/publications/SY10.pdf) by Shpilka, and Yehudayoff is a good resource. Also, a lower bound of $2^{\Omega(n)}$ on the size of monotone circuits for the permanent is known as well (proved by [Jerrum and Snir](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322341))